# Selenium click action on a webElement does not work when changing to a 4K monitor (3840 x 2160)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an electron application and I am using Selenium for automatic testing. The application was displayed on a full hd monitor and **click action** on webElements was working fine. However, after changing the monitor to a 4k monitor, the click action does not respond.

This action does work for Full HD resolution but not for 4K:

```
webElement.Click();
```

I have to use JavaScriptExecutor instead to make it works. This way it does work:

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

I would like to understand why Selenium click method has stopped working when changing screen resolution. I have tried to change ChromeOptions to set the screen resolution but it does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking the element, scroll the element to centre of screen using javascript executor and check, if it works.

Comment: I am able to click on the elements with javascript executor. My goal is to do it with Selenium C# methods as I was doing with a resolution full HD. Scrolling into the element before clicking does not solve the problem...

Comment: Also check, if you are providing xpath or other locator strategy for child element. Sometimes, normal clicks doesn't work on parent element, in that case, we need to provide the path explicitly up to the child element.